# Unable to execute Spring-data Couchbase query

Tags: spring-data, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I've a spring-data couchbase repository. I'm trying to query the database using n1ql queries through the @Query annotation. A basic repository I implemented looks like this:

```
public interface CouchBaseRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<GsJsonStore, Long> {
@Query("SELECT * FROM default WHERE ?0 = ?1")
public Page<GsJsonStore> matchJson(String term, String value, Pageable pageable);�
}�
```

When I try to query using this method I get the error:

```
Unable to execute the query due to the following errors:
{"msg":"syntax error - at 0","code":3000}
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for inline query is plain `N1QL`, which uses `$` instead of `?`.

**HOWEVER** note that `@Query` with a handcrafted query isn't always the best idea, since it has caveats to write one.

In order to unmarshall the entity correctly, the query should also extract some metadata: the ID of the document (which becomes the entity's `@Id`) and the CAS (which becomes the entity's `@Version`)...

Also, since in Couchbase data of any type can be mixed in the same backing bucket, the query should always filter on the correct `_class` attribute.

So your query would be best rewritten using utility SpEL in order to take all that into consideration:

```
@Query("#n1ql.selectEntity WHERE $0 = $1 AND #n1ql.filter")
```

`selectEntity` will be replaced by the adequate "`SELECT default.*, META(default).ID AS id, META(default).CAS AS cas FROM default`".
Similarly, `filter` will be replaced by the adequate where clause "`_class = 'com.packege.here.GsJsonStore'`".

Answer (score 0):

Replacing '?' with '$' fixed the issue.